# Error - No such module CCXGoogleSDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-api, cocoapods

I have to fetch all nearby ATM and for this I am using CCXGoogleNearbyPlaces framework using cocoapods (Reference: https://cocoapods.org/pods/CCXGoogleNearbyPlaces)

But I am not able to use CCXGoogleSDK class. I am getting this error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should need to import CCXGoogleNearbyPlaces.

**import CCXGoogleNearbyPlaces** instead of **import CCXGoogleSDK**

[image]

[image]

Comment: let me know if this is helpful for you?